# How to "export" iOS Application from start to finish - Simplified for an Android dev

Tags: android, ios, xcode

I'm coming from an Android background so please bear with me.

I'm having a really tough time grasping the concepts of certificates, identifiers, and provisioning profile. I have signed up for a developer account, and (hopefully) gone through the correct steps to create a certificate and provisioning profile for production/distribution. I have tried looking up a guide for the newest xcode that would "walk" me through the whole process, but I keep finding old and outdated resources. I was just wondering if someone could go through the steps you need to export an iOS app.

I've followed the Apple Distribution guide, but I'm still very "confused". Again, I've never worked/developed/released on any platform besides Android, and I guess they made it very easy.

[Apple states:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/SubmittingYourApp/SubmittingYourApp.html)

- Create a distribution certificate.
- Create a store distribution provisioning profile.
- Archive and validate your app.
- For Mac apps, test the Mac Installer Package.
- Submit your app using Xcode or Application Loader.

  1. I've created a distribution certificate. The "name" of it is my Companies name.
  2. I've created a store distribution provisioning profile. The "name" of it is my Apps name.

So I'm confused with both of these things. Should I keep them secret? Should I download and save them? Also, what the hell is this wild card identifier.

I understand this is a broad question, and it may get flagged for being too specific, but I hope I am not the only person having this problem.

Answer (score 2):

what do you mean by export an app?  If you want to distribute the app to testers/clients you'll need to do the following steps:

1. Add devices to you apple account
2. Add devices to your development distribution profile
3. In xcode -> preferences -> accounts, double lick the iOS account (lower right corner) and hit refresh.  This will pull down your new development profile with new devices.
4. In xcode, check your bundle identifier matches your provisioning profile (either in info.plist or targets->general->bundle identifier
5. in targets -> build settings, make sure 'code signing identity' is set to the same identity the provision profile uses.
6. in menu, select product -> archive.  if build is successful, this will launch organizer.
7. in organizer, selected the most recent build, and click distribute
8. select save for enterprise or ad hoc deployment
9. select the development provisioning profile and export your app.  It will now install and run on any of the devices you set up in step 1.